# My global variable isn't found in another function

Tags: python, python-3.x, global-variables

I assign `remaining_length` the value of stock length. Stock length is assigned in another function and is also global.  I try to run the code and it tells me that I am using the variable before assignment.  I have declared and used other global variables through my code and haven't had this issue, until now.  Also, why does it recognize my global variable `all_possible_cutting_options`, but not `remaining_length`?  I moved `remaining_length` into `get_next_possible_cutting_option()` and it works, but I need to save the value for `remaining_length` and use it again the next time I call `get_next_possible_cutting_option()`, rather than reset the value back to `stock_length` every time.

```
def get_all_possible_cutting_options_for_a_bar():
    global all_possible_cutting_options
    global remaining_length
    remaining_length = stock_length
    all_possible_cutting_options = []
    another_cutting_option_possible = get_another_cutting_option_possible()
    while another_cutting_option_possible:
        get_next_possible_cutting_option()
        another_cutting_option_possible = get_another_cutting_option_possible()

def get_next_possible_cutting_option():
    cutting_option = []
    for cut in cuts_ordered:
        if remaining_length >= cut.length:
            cut.quantity = remaining_length // cut.length
            remaining_length -= cut.length * cut.quantity
            cutting_option.append(cut)
        else:
            cut.quantity = 0
            cutting_option.append(cut)
    all_possible_cutting_options.append(cutting_option)
```

**Error:**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main-v3.0.py", line 91, in <module>
    get_all_possible_cutting_options_for_a_bar()
  File "main-v3.0.py", line 41, in get_all_possible_cutting_options_for_a_bar
    get_next_possible_cutting_option()
  File "main-v3.0.py", line 56, in get_next_possible_cutting_option
    if remaining_length >= cut.length:
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'remaining_length' referenced before assignment
```

Comment: You must declare a variable as `global` in any function that assigns a value to it.

Comment: @martineau Did I do that wrong? I thought I did that when I declared it global and then immediately assigned it the value equal to "stock_length"

Comment: Please [edit] your question add the entire traceback which will indicate the line the error is occurring on (among other things).

Comment: Why are you using so many global variables?

Comment: I cant help you, I got -2 for giving you an answer

Comment: @chepner I have been using them because I thought it would be the simplest way to have my variables used throughout multiple functions.  Is there a better way you  could recommend?

Comment: Yes: pass arguments to your functions, and have them return values.

Comment: @K.Kretz are you using threads?

Comment: @chepner not if he uses threads

Comment: @Martin Global variables are an even *worse* idea if you are using threads, as now you need to synchronize access to them.

Comment: @chepner Thank you.  I thought using a global variable would be easier becuase I would need several outputs per function, but I try this.

Comment: @chepner who said I would use global variables? I asked him if he uses threads so I would make for him good solution.

Comment: @Martin I am not sure what threads are, so I don't think I am using them.

Comment: threads are 'paralel' programs. If you run one function after another, than @chepner solution is the way things should be done. You pass variables from function to function. And if you do something with variable, you need to return it at the end of the function. If you are using threads, it can happen that 2 functions wants to modify the same variable at the same time... That can cause problems. Since you dont use threads, I wont explain you what to do with such cases...

Comment: Thanks for the explanation @Martin!

Comment: @Martin  I asked why he was using globals and said he should be using function arguments and return values instead. What was your comment addressed to me supposed to mean?

Comment: @chepner I didnt like your lecture to my question on OP which only asked him whether he uses threads or not

Comment: @Martin I'm trying to figure out why you said to *me* "not if he uses threads*. I never commented on your question.

Comment: @chepner Ah sorry, that was reply on your 'pass arguments to your function'. Which could be pretty wrong if he would use threads. Since a lot of beginners uses global variables as a solution to sharing states in threads, I asked him, if he uses threads... then came your unwanted lecture

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that while `remaining_length` is global in your first function, it's *local* in your second one. This is because you *assign* to `remaining_length` (`remaining_length -= cut.length * cut.quantity`). To fix this, simply add a `global` declaration to that function as well:

```
def get_next_possible_cutting_option():
    global remaining_length
```

Comment: Not at all. `global x` will create a global variable x if it doesn't exist. Even I thought so, but I just checked.

Comment: Right you are. I will rescind this answer.

Comment: @DiptangsuGoswami Thanks for the tip: I think I discovered the actual problem.